# git fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'git+https'

Tags: macos, npm

I'm having issue upgrading my npm packages.
It uses `git+https` for cloning, but my git is failing with `fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'git+https'`

Weird thing is that a `git clone https://github.com/foobar/somerepo.git` worked fine.

I'm running `git 2.4.5` (installed via Homebrew) and tried OSX native `curl 7.37.1` and even Homebrews `curl 7.43.0`
, also running `OSX 10.10.4`

git seems fine, too:

`git --exec-path
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.4.5/libexec/git-core`

Any hint what could be wrong with my setup/in my case?

Comment: I've never seen `git+https://` as a protocol before. Normally you would uses `git://` *or* `https://`. Are you sure that `git+https://` should work?

Comment: yes! https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install states it's a valid protocol.

Comment: Interesting. This certainly is [*not* listed as a valid protocol in the Git documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#URLS), unless you consider the degenerate case of falling back to a third-party transport helper (which your error seems to indicate). Perhaps it's NPM-specific?

Comment: Yes these URLs are valid due to https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize-git-url which is used by npm, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a bug in the current `npm@2.12.1`.

An [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8881) has been submitted